# Modifying SOAP Envelope XML Before Making request

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I've been trying to connect to a web service using node-soap but keep on getting the error "Cannot read property 'Body' of undefined".  I believe the problem is that the SOAP envelope generated by node-soap is incorrect and needs to use ns1 instead of tns.  Please see the envelope generated by PHP's SoapClient which successfully connects to the web service and node-soap's generated envelope below:

PHP

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:IsHealthy/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Node-SOAP

```
    <soap:Body>
        <tns:IsHealthy xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        </tns:IsHealthy>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a setting to tell node soap to use ns1 or a way to modify the envelope before sending?

Answer (score 0):

During create client , you could pass parameter :

```
var options = {
   envelopeKey:'soapenv',
   xmlKey: 'sdm'
  };
soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {

}
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#options)